# How to make Flink write to HDFS everytime the window is finished?

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink, real-time

I am a begineer of Flink, my problem is, my Flink App consume a real-time flow, I'd like to aggregate the uv of the flow for every 'natural' hour, and then write the agg results to HDFS. I can use

```
ds.window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(1))).maxBy(1)
```

to achieve the aggregation work, but to write every hour, however, the bucketingSink class can only accept time interval start at the start of program, not the 'natural' hour, like, starting at 14:50:00, next time been triggered will be 15:50:00, not 15:00:00. The function is

```
bucketingSink.setBatchRolloverInterval(1*60*1000L)
```

I currently cannot find the solution to make the writing process to be triggered everytime the window function is finished, can anyone give me some hints?
Thanks loads.

Comment: What version of Flink are you using? The bucketing sink was deprecated and removed some time ago. Are you able to use the FileSink or StreamingFileSink?

Comment: @DavidAnderson my Flink version is 1.9.1. I haven't heard of FileSink/StreamingFileSink, is it supported at 1.9.1? Thx

Answer (score 1):

The BucketingSink had some flaws and was already deprecated in Flink 1.9; it was removed in Flink 1.12. I suggest you update your sink to use the StreamingFileSink: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html.

Then you will want to implement a custom [bucket assigner](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/BucketAssigner.html) and perhaps a [rolling policy](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/RollingPolicy.html).